# cakephp 2.0 integration with paypal

Tags: cakephp, paypal

Hello everyone,
               I am new to paypal but now the basics of cakephp, rightnow I am making a  paypal integration with cakephp but unable to pass the value to the paypal. I'm showing you my code. Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

```
function paypal()
{
  if($this->request->is('post'))
  {
      echo $item_name_1=$this->request->data['Choose']['item_name_1'];
      echo"<br>";
      echo $amount_1=$this->request->data['Choose']['amount_1'];echo"<br>";
      echo $item_name_2=$this->request->data['Choose']['item_name_2'];echo"<br>";
      echo $amount_2=$this->request->data['Choose']['amount_2'];echo"<br>";
      echo $cmd=$this->request->data['Choose']['cmd'];echo"<br>";
      echo $business=$this->request->data['Choose']['business'];echo"<br>";
      echo $upload=$this->request->data['Choose']['upload'];echo"<br>";
      echo $currency_code=$this->request->data['Choose']['currency_code'];echo"<br>";
      echo $item_number_1=$this->request->data['Choose']['item_number_1'];echo"<br>";
      echo $item_number_2=$this->request->data['Choose']['item_number_2'];echo"<br>";
      $this->redirect('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd='.$cmd.'&upload='.$upload.'&business='.$business.
                      '&currency_code='.$currency_code.'&item_number_1='.$item_number_1.'&item_name_1='.$item_name_1.
                      '&'.'amount_1='.$amount_1.'&item_number_2='.$item_number_2.'&item_name_2='.$item_name_2.'&'.'amount_2='.$amount_2);

   }
}
```

I'm passing all the view values(including hidden fields) to my controller(all values are displaying correctly) and redirecting it to the paypal site. Here I'm sending multiple values but I'm getting error like this:

```
This recipient is currently unable to receive money.
```

If i write the same code in corephp then values are reaching to the paypal and everything working fine, please tell me where I'm getting wrong.

Comment: I found a solution for this if i replace the existing url with 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' , then value is reaching to the paypal but if i replace this with the original 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' then it shows the same error again. How to solve this, please help.

Comment: I did it .....for freshers i wanaa tell u if u want to integrate with paypal then firstly create a account at sandbox paypal. It's for free and u can test ur code here after that login into ur account and click on the 'TestAccounts' link and create a buyer account and seller account. When you brought your items(buying something) to paypal, then login with ur buyer paypal id and password and its done next step u will click on the pay button and u will get a reciept regrading your transaction whicch you can see in ur paypal account. Tht's it..have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should prepare your code in the Controller:

```
function paypal(){
   $this->set('paypalData', $this->request->data['Choose']);
}
```

... and then create a **form** (in a view) which is POSTed to the PayPal site:

```
//file: Views/ControllerName/paypal.ctp
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalData['business']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $paypalData['business']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="<?php echo $paypalData['item_name_1']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="<?php echo $paypalData['item_number_1']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="<?php echo $paypalData['amount_1']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $paypalData['currency_code']; ?>">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

The user would then click the button to go to PayPal, which is more reliable (and right :D). The url which you are redirecting to might fail in many ways, since your values are not url_encoded, might get too long, etc..

Second: Your error is probably popping up because you are using **www.paypal.com** instead of **www.sandbox.paypal.com**

Third: I copied the HTML above to ease the viewing, you should be using the Form helper inside the view to ensure proper HTML formatting.

Fourth: ECHOing inside a Controller action is just wrong. Especially so, if you are redirecting after making output. Redirects will not work if any output is sent to the browser.

Hope this gets you in the right direction.